# populate after object has been saved

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i'm updating my object and after the update has finished i'd like to display a success message which says sth. like "Success - Your Object at address: 123 was saved". Therefore i'd like to populate a property after the save has been done.

```
terminal.save(function (err, updatedTerminal) {
     if (err) return handleError(err);

     updatedTerminal.populate('installedAt');

     res.send(updatedTerminal);
});
```

but `installedAt` will not be populated - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`populate` is a function of `Mongoose` model and here `updatedTerminal` is not a `Mongoose` model.

`functions` like `find`, `findOne` returns `Mongoose Object` a special kind of object which has all the functions available like `Model` but `save` method only returns pure **Javascript** `object` after saving the document.